# In google calendar api, get a list of events that are occurring "now"?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

What is the simplest way to get a list of events that are occurring "now", or at any given *moment*?

I was going for `events/list` ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list ).
There I can specify an interval (with start and end time), but the search doesn't return events that "intersect" with my interval, it returns only events which are completely "contained" in it.

This makes querying for a "moment" rather difficult, since the events are of unknown length (they could span several days) and I can't just add "some hours" to expand my interval bounds. This means I actually would have to fetch the whole calendar and do all my querying locally (resolving recurring events myself *and stuff*), making the whole api rather useless in this case.

I don't think my use case is that strange, maybe I overlooked something?